# MATLAB Plotting-Group Super Object

Tags: matlab, plot, alignment, histogram

In MATLAB, I would like to create a super "visualization" object that, for example, creates within it a normal `plot()` object together with its corresponding histogram (typically placed on the right of the `plot()`), `hist()`. These naturally shares the y-dimension of the plot which means they should juxtapositioned along that dimensions without any unneccesary  padding a la `subplot`.

A parameter should enable the user to set the *relative* width of the standard plot and the histogram. This super object should then be used in another grouping such as a set of subplots. How do I accomplish this?

We often want to visualize different aspects of our data and this grouping object would make this easier....

Comment: Something like [scatterhist](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/scatterhist.html)?

Comment: It sounds like you just need `subplot`, and possibly `linkaxes`.

Comment: @Jonas: Oh, I didn't know of `scatterhist`. Seems nice. But I want more than just that specific case. Those were just an illustrating example. I already use `linkaxes`. But `subplot` creates too much padding and cannot control relative size of subplots. It probably boils down to some algorithm calling `axes`. I also would like this to work with GUI Layout Toolbox.

Comment: @Nordlöw: You **can** control the size of subplots.  Take a look at the documentation: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/subplot.html.

Comment: There is also [subaxis](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3696-subaxis-subplot) to make controlling subplots easier, or [axshift](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23680-axshift) if you want to manually control your axes.